# copying selected columns from one table to another using trigger in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

In table1, I have 3 columns (let's say with columns Name, Age(which is already running on a trigger), Occupation). I want to copy only the 'Name' and 'Age' columns into another table 'table2'.

I saw some previous posts on this topic, however I am not able to create a trigger **in table2**(not table1 cuz I already have a complicated trigger in there).

I did the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg
AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table2 SET Name = NEW.Name, Age = NEW.Age;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg
AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table2 SET table2.Name = NEW.Name, table2.Age = NEW.Age;
END
```

Add table2. in front of column headings.

Comment: so like I said above, I already have a trigger and when I use yours, it says that multiple triggers can't be possible.